# Invalid setting error for activity log alerts ARM Template

Tags: infrastructure-as-code, azure-alerts, azure-monitor

Getting below error for deploying action group and alert rule. Action group deploys successfully but alert rule is failing deployment.Any help will be appreciated to resolve these issues. No issue creating through the portal. Issue is seen when using ARM Template.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/resource-manager-alerts-activity-log
**
Error Message**
`{ "code": "DeploymentFailed", "target": "/subscriptions/<>/resourceGroups/<>/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/Microsoft.Template-20230428080745", "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.", "details": [ { "code": "InvalidSetting", "target": "/subscriptions/<>/resourceGroups/<>/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/Microsoft.Template-20230428080745", "message": "Error parsing request payload Activity ID: ." } ] }`

**Template file**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "actionGroups_name": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "action"
  
      },
      "activityLogAlerts_name": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "action-alert"
      },
      "emailAddress": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "variables": {
      "alertScope": "[format('/subscriptions/{0}', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name)]"
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "microsoft.insights/actionGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
        "name": "[parameters('actionGroups_name')]",
        "location": "Global",
        "properties": {
          "groupShortName": "[parameters('actionGroups_name')]",
          "enabled": true,
          "emailReceivers": [
            {
              "name": "[parameters('actionGroups_name')]",
              "emailAddress": "[parameters('emailAddress')]"
            }
          ],
          "smsReceivers": [],
          "webhookReceivers": []
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "microsoft.insights/activityLogAlerts",
        "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
        "name": "[parameters('activityLogAlerts_name')]",
        "location": "Global",
        "properties": {
          "scopes": "[variables('alertScope')]",
          "condition": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "category",
                "equals": "Administrative"
              },
              {
                "field": "resourceType",
                "equals": "microsoft.cloudtest/images"
              },
              {
                "field": "operationName",
                "equals": "Microsoft.CloudTest/images/refresh/action"
              }
            ]
          },
          "actions": {
            "actionGroups": [
              {
                "actionGroupId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', parameters('actionGroups_name'))]",
                "webhookProperties": {}
              }
            ]
          },
          "enabled": true
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', parameters('actionGroups_name'))]"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```